# Period of a state i in a Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I'm using the book titled, *Essential of Stochastic Process* by Durret which is known to be rampant with errors.

Here is a part of the text which is confusing me:

[image]

and I'd like to know if this is an error on the author's part or due to my lack of understanding.

> Definition:
>
> The period of a state i in a Markov chain is some largest number which divides the number of step n such that
> $p^{n}\left (i,i  \right ) \forall n\geq 1$.

In the example given below, I fail to observe why $p^{n}\left (0,0  \right )>0$...
From the table, $p\left (0,0  \right )=0$ and any exponent on this is 0....

Any clarification is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to notice is that If you go to the left, you will be back at $0$ in 3 steps. If you go to the right, you will be back at $0$ in 4 steps. Since these happen with equal probability, we must have $p^3(0,0) = 1/2 = p^4(0,0)$.

If you compute the matrix powers properly, you will see this is indeed the case.

Comment: Thank you! This explains why I feel as though the concepts are contradictory with each other; turns out the issues lies with my misunderstanding of the notation!